# System.Threading.Timer - Am I using it right?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I use some `System.Threading.Timer(s)` in my multithreading application (three such timers actually), but, despite the fact that it's working very well, I have the feeling that I'm doing it wrong and that I consume unnecessary resources. Practically, what I am doing is this :

1. In the main window of my application (WPF window, but don't think that it matters so much) I open three threads.
2. in every of those three threads, I initialize and start one of the three timers

The reason that I'm using three different threads to do this is because I remember that I've read somewhere (can't find where) that when I start a `System.Threading.Timer` I can no longer use the current thread (like the thread would stop somehow at the Timer starting).

Now, I have tested the next simple application and there appears to be no conflict between the Timer and the thread that starts it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    System.Threading.Timer _t1, _t2, _t3;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _t1 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(_t1Run),
                           null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15));
        _t2 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(_t2Run),
               null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(35));
        _t3 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(_t3Run),
               null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Writting on main form " + i);
        }
    }

    void _t1Run(object State)
    {
        _t1.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        Console.WriteLine("running 1");
        _t1.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15));
    }

    void _t2Run(object State)
    {
        _t2.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        Console.WriteLine("running 2");
        _t2.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(35), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(35));
    }

    void _t3Run(object State)
    {
        _t3.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        Console.WriteLine("running 3");
        _t3.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
    }

}
```

So, can I just start all my three Timers on the main window (or I need separate threads) ? Can someone confirm that this causes no problems (because in the application that I've tested it doesn't appear to be any problem) ?

**Edit**: 
The three timers have different purposes, and two of them actually have some UI interaction (one interacts with the main window and the other with a secondary window - the third doing just some background operations), but the reason for which I do not use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is that the timers make a lot of operations and if I would do all those operations on the main thread, than I would practically block all the GUI interactions (I call those timer-threads at an interval of 100-200 milliseconds, so just imagine ...) .
That's an example of how I do the GUI interactions from the threads called by the Timers:

```
MainWindow.ThisInstance.TitleLabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateMainWindow_TimeLabel(TimeLabelValue)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Threading.Timer` if you have some kind UI element interaction in the Timer callback code.

System.Threading.Timer spins out a threadpool thread whenever the timespan elapsed. But this can create problem with Form elements as they are not thread safe. Accessing UI elements using threads other then the dedicated UI thread can create unwanted result.

To overcome this thread unsafe behavior System.Windows.Forms.Timer should be used. System.Windows.Forms.Timer doesn't create new thread or spin a new threadpool thread. It just run the timer callback in the UI thread. That way all UI interactions are performed in a single thread which ensures thread safty .

But if your timer callback takes significant amount of time to finish then your UI will freeze so System.Windows.Forms.Timer should only be used for very short task.
For longer background task you can use `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`

Comment: It is better to give explanation in your answer. Indeed, those timers exist for different purposes.

Comment: @nhrobin, , well,doing the next trick it tells me that the label is updated in the GUI thread :

    `MainWindow.ThisInstance.TitleLabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateMainWindow_TimeLabel(TimeLabelValue))); `

        `private static void UpdateMainWindow_TimeLabel(String TimeLabelValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name of thread running this: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            MainWindowInstance.TimeLabel.Content = TimeLabelValue;
        } `

Comment: @nhrobin, the System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker also seems a viable solution. Just want to better understand first why my solution is not (so) good, giving the fact that Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() seems to do the trick (and it apparently makes all the iterations in the GUI thread).

Comment: @TheQuestioner Your solution is perfectly alright.  There is only some readability issues. As you can see you have to write much longer statement to update simple label MainWindow.ThisInstance.TitleLabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateMainWindow_TimeLabel(TimeLabelValue)));

Comment: @nhrobin, Yeah, I didn't like it to much either. So should I do so: 1. replace the 3 timers with 3 System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker(s) (it's important to be 3, because the secondary window is not always available and the third thread run's much more complicated operations than the first 2) ; 2.   I use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer to call RunWorkerAsync() for the BackgroundWorker(s). This is what you were suggesting me from what I understand, right ?

Comment: @nhrobin, Also, could I just put my Forms.Timer and the eventHandler in the `public partial class App : Application `(App.xaml.cs) without blocking the MainWindow ? (it's no problem to leave it in the MainWindow, it's just that it would look more nice that way)

Comment: For the complicated task you surly can go for the BackgroundWorker. But for simpler ones I think you can stick to your current implementation as implementing BackgroundWorker will rather introduce more codes/complexity.

Comment: @nhrobin, Ok, I'll take this in consideration for the first two threads, but I'll surely use the BackgroundWorker for the third one. So, for my initial question : should I use separate threads to start the timers or I can use the main thread ?

Comment: There is no need of using separate thread to start a timer. You can use the main thread without any problem.